# How to segment ocular region in a face separately as left eye and right eye?

Tags: opencv, image-processing, computer-vision, biometrics

I have tried using pre-trained haar-cascades from OpenCV library but there were many false positives. Is there any efficient way without using haar-cascades?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no perfect solution that I know of, but some preprocessing will make the results better.

- detect eyes only in the top half of the face. Further more, detect left eye in the left half of the top-half region of the face. This will help you eliminate false positives. But this will also reduce true positives. Give it a try as I am not sure what exactly your images looks like.
- Since you asked for some method other than haar-cascades, you can try dlib landmark detection. It is very fast and quite accurate for frontal faces. [Python version [here](http://dlib.net/face_landmark_detection.py.html), C++ version [here]](http://dlib.net/face_landmark_detection_ex.cpp.html) . I have used this with good success.

Since I am also trying to solve this problem, do let me know how this worked for you :)